# preventing user to go back once logged out in laravel 5

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-5

I have a logout function like this

```
public function logout() {
        Auth::logout(); // logout user
        return Redirect::to('login'); //redirect back to login
    }
```

When logout function is triggered through routes which looks like

```
Route::get('logout', array(
    'uses' => 'userController@logout'
));
```

user get redirected to the login page. But when goes back using browser, dashboard view gets opened which i don't want to. What can be the best way to prevent users from going back to dashboard once they logged out? Though there are some discussion on this topic, but didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the Auth, you can utilise the existing Middleware to stop the back button putting them on dashboard.

Wrap the routes you want to protect with a [Route::group](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Any attempt to access dashboard without login will put them back on the home page (default location in the middleware). Modify the middleware (found in app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php) to change the redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a middleware in your dashboard so that even if they press back the button they can go back to the page but can't do anything unless they login again.